# Shortcut for if/else partial rendering in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I saw something like it somewhere (was specifically if an entity was nil, then don't display the partial), but I can't seem to duplicate the functionality. Is there any way to shorthand the following?

```
<% if @sales_orders.any? %>                             
<%= render @sales_orders %>                             
<% else %>                             
<%= render 'shared/no_records' %>
<% end %>
```

Something like:

```
<%= render @sales_orders || 'no records found' %>
```

or (pseudo, but you get the drift):

```
<%= @sales_orders ? render(@sales_orders) : render('shared/no_records') %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're pretty close with your pseudo, I think:

```
<%= render(@sales_orders.any? ? @sales_orders : 'shared/no_records') %>
```

Comment: Hah! So close yet so far away. Much appreciated.